# Do I need to clone an Ubuntu system drive to make a bootable copy?

Tags: cloning

I like to make bootable copies of my system drives so that when the drive eventually fails, I can replace it and be running again in minutes. With Windows it is necessary to clone the system drive because a copy will not boot. A copy is of course a defragmented alphabetical copy, while a clone puts all the data in exactly the same sectors as they were in on the original drive. Of course, if the system drive could simply be copied it would have several advantages. One is that the system drive could be copied to a larger drive if needed, while a clone cannot use the extra space of a larger drive.
I am running Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. This is a Dell Mini Tower, less than a year old. It has only one hard drive. I am talking about copying the whole drive. I am not concerned with my data because I always back  it up.
My question for Ask Ubuntu is if an Ubuntu system drive needs to be cloned, or if it can simply be copied, to make a bootable replacement.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. it is not clear what you are asking. One of the issue is your use of the term "Ubuntu system drive". Windows uses the word drive to mean either a physical solid state drive (SSD)  /  hard disk drive (HDD) or a partition within a SSD/HDD. So when you save clone a system drive, it is not clear if you mean cloning the SSD/HDD or the system partition. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1453610/edit) and improve it. Also include information about whether your computer uses legacy BIOS with MBR or newer UEFI with GPT.

Comment: Generally cloning is not best backup method. How often are you going to totally refresh that clone. It is out of date, as soon as you use your system. Most do not backup Ubuntu system as it is easy to reinstall. But do backup all data, list of installed apps, changes to system settings in /etc and if server apps, those folders in / (may require system shutdown to get all data).  Then you can easily refresh changes without copying everything all over again. Some like a image, using Clonezilla.

Comment: I am talking about the hard disk drive. There is only one. I always back up my data. I back up my WIndows system drives because you can't always get windows again, if you don't have the disk, or the required version. Or you have to repurchase software to have a version compatible with the new version.

Comment: Purchasing, reinstalling and configuring software can take days, weeks. I don't have that kind of time. Once programs are installed and configured, rarely make changes so clone is rarely out of date. This is a Dell mini-tower, less than a year old. Have no idea if legacy BOIS, MBR or UEFI. I first wanted to ask this question long before finding Ask Ubuntu, just to know the answer for future planning.

Comment: Then I suddenly found I am out of disk space. Was thinking if I could just copy I could copy to a larger drive. I freed up a bit of disk space. I ended up powering off and now after seeing the Dell symbol, then Dell with Ubuntu and a busy sign, then a black screen. I tried several things such as holding down shift while booting. Not able to get anything. Any suggestions ? Calling Dell tomorrow for technical support. Will update the original question.

Comment: I was unable to recover computer with Dell's help. They want me to re-install Linux. I am going to try other things before giving up on this installation. Meanwhile, Dell told me I could have simply copied the hard drive and had a bootable copy. I will completely re-write my question above and remove all these comments if I can. I just thought I would let anyone who is watching, know what is happening.